# How to get the data used in a .html web page?

Tags: html, database, flash

I want to get the questions that are used in a game on a .html page.
The game is on this link: http://www.tv5monde.com/TV5Site/qpuc/qpuc_frameset.html
It's a famous TV show, like a sort of equivalent of Jeopardy in France and there is this online version which asks questions randomly. I want to know if it's possible to get the list of the questions and answers that are used in this page, if there is a sort of database file available thanks to the link or something ?

I am not very good with that stuff so if you could help it would be nice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"I want to know if it's possible to get the list of the questions and answers that are used in this page, if there is a sort of database file available "*

You can use your browser's own "Developer Tools" (eg: in Chrome use `ctrl+shift+i` to open the tool). From there you can see all files being accessed via http requests.

- See if anything like a `.txt` or `.xml` or `.json` etc file is being accessed,
- Check contents in a new tab, which might contain the questions.

For this one, questions are stored in file `gameXXX.txt` where`XXX` is a number between **1** and **200**.

```
http://www.tv5monde.com/TV5Site/qpuc/games/game1.txt
```

examples:

http://www.tv5monde.com/TV5Site/qpuc/games/game1.txt

http://www.tv5monde.com/TV5Site/qpuc/games/game85.txt

http://www.tv5monde.com/TV5Site/qpuc/games/game200.txt

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is an officially documented way/api you need to get creative. For these types of data scraping tasks, the same tools used for end-to-end testing can be useful. E.g. cypress could be used for this. Of course you need to consider what you want to do is not actually legal and you need to proceed with caution.